# Facebook time format?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, datetime

Quick question: is there an easy way to convert the raw time given from the facebook API to the time format seen on the facebook app? If all else fails, a new algorithm could be written, but I'm sure it's out there already (but apparently not on SO - I searched that).

The time on the facebook app goes like so:
"3 seconds ago"
"5 minutes ago"
"19 hours ago"
"yesterday at blah blah"
etc. etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Google is your friend...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [PrettyTime](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/) library. It's very easy to use. For example:

```
PrettyTime prettyTime = new PrettyTime(Locale.getDefault());
String theString = prettyTime.format(theDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook times are stored in three different formats. Try use this method to convert the time string data to Calendar

```
 public static Calendar convertToCalendar(String strDate) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf;
    if (strDate.length() >= 22)
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ");
    else if (strDate.length() > 12)
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss");
    else {
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }

    try {
        sdf.parse(strDate);
        cal.setTime(sdf.parse(strDate));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        cal = null;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cal;

}
```

Than you can create a new Calendar instance and perform your calculation to format the time text like you want.
I suggest you to use [Joda-Time Library](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to help you to perform time calculations. You can obtain the hours, minutes and seconds difference in this way:

```
Hours.hoursBetween(cal1, cal2) 
Minutes.minutesBetween(cal1, cal2)
Seconds.secondsBetween(cal1, cal2)
```